# How to change language?

Tags: android, jetpack-joyride

Recently Halfbrick updated an update for Jetpack Joyride and it automatically changed the game language to my System Language (pt-br).

The biggest problem is that their translation to pt-br is not very good, it's full of errors and it just ruined the game's atmosphere. I don't want to change the system language just to play a game so, can anyone tell me how to change it back?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible, according to their [help page](https://halfbrick.helpshift.com/a/jetpack-joyride/?s=general&f=how-do-i-change-my-language):

> At the current point in time there is no way to change your language
>   from within Jetpack Joyride.
>
> The game automatically mirrors whichever language is active on your
>   device, unless your language is not supported in which case it should
>   revert to English.
>
> We are hoping to change this system in a future update and will post
>   more information as soon as it becomes available.
>
> In the meantime, changing your language at the device level should do
>   the trick.